# Understanding the accuracy metric in TensorFlow Keras for multi-label classification tasks

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I have the following model code:

```
model_lstm.add(Embedding(256, 250, input_length=640))
model_lstm.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.4))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(50))
model_lstm.add(Dense(12, activation='**sigmoid**'))

model_lstm.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='**binary_crossentropy**',
              metrics=['**accuracy**', 'AUC'])
```

I have seen answers that scikit-learn and Keras define the accuracy metric differently. What exactly does the metric show:

1. Does accuracy show that on average n% of examples in the test set were classified correctly?
2. Does accuracy mean that on average n% of labels in each example were predicted correctly?
   What is a "label" in Keras in this case: an instance that is correctly classified by all labels or each label of each instance?

Comment: assume you have  5 numbers `[1,1,4,2,3]` and the model predicts them to be `[1,2,4,3,3]` the model got 3 out of 5 of the numbers correctly thus accuracy will be `3/5=0.6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the metrics args text in [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile) it is stated:

> When you pass the strings 'accuracy' or 'acc', we convert this to one
> of tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy,
> tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy,
> tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy based on the shapes of the
> targets and of the model output.

I wasn't sure if the string 'accuracy' goes to `BinaryAccuracy` or `CategoricalAccuracy` for multi-label, and how the metrics deal with multi-label input. So I did a little testing (I never worked with Multi-class labels before):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

y =  [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 1.0 ], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]] #  ground truth
x =  [[0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.6, 0.05], [0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.9, 0.2]]
x2 = [[0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.6, 0.05], [0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.6, 0.2]]

print(tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy(y, x))
# tf.Tensor([1. 0.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
print(tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy(y, x2))
# tf.Tensor([1. 1.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
print(tf.keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(y, x))
# tf.Tensor([0.8 1. ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
print(tf.keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(y, x2))
# tf.Tensor([0.8 1. ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

`y` is the ground truth for two samples with multiple labels. `x` and `x2` are almost the same, both has only one label correct in the first sample, and both have both labels correct in the second one. The difference is that I switched the logits for the correct classes in the second sample (0.6 and 0.9).

You can see that categorical crossentropy doesn't really work here. The reason is that [internally](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/601488fd4c1468ae7872e132e0f1c9843df54182/keras/metrics/accuracy_metrics.py#L426), it uses `argmax` on the ground truth labels, and then does `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. This is the reason why for `x` it has 0.0 accuracy for the second sample, and for `x2` it is 1.0. It just checks for the first 1 in the ground truth, if that is also the highest logit in the predicition.
Binary crossentropy on the other hand looks better. It just compares how many 0's and 1's fit after thresholding the logits with a threshold of 0.5. Everything under 0.5 goes to 0, everything else goes to 1.

I did another test to see what the model would pick with 'accuracy':

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x)])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
pred = model.evaluate(x, y)
# 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 141ms/step - loss: 0.4936 - accuracy: 0.5000 - binary_accuracy: 0.9000
pred = model.evaluate(x2, y)
# 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 37ms/step - loss: 0.4936 - accuracy: 1.0000 - binary_accuracy: 0.9000
```

The model has nothing to learn, the lambda layer just troughputs the data. It seems that 'accuracy' picks `categoical crossentropy`. This could be because the model here is so basic and weirdly shaped, that TF can't detect that the problem is multi-label. But in general, I'd be careful with the string 'accuracy' as a metric when dealing with multi-label classification.

Comment: First the `y` you used is ambiguous as it is not a one hot encoding. The cross entropy is for classification of mutually exclusive datapoints. One input cannot have two labels, unless I am mistake. thus `y` should only have a one in one of the places if it is a one hot encoded vector

Comment: The whole question is about a _multi_-label classification, so yeah, there should be more than one 1 in `y` (or more specific, one or more 1's). And yes, I showed that `categorical crossentropy` can only handle normal classification with one class per label, and that the 'accuracy' string picks `categorical crossentropy` at least in my dummy model, which would not work for multi-label cases.